# Algebraization of vector bundles over non-algebraically closed fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, formal-schemes

I've asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4014524/algebraically-closedness-on-a-theorem-of-hartshorne) but never got an answer, a simplified version of the question is the following:

Given an intersection of hypersurfaces $Y$ on a smooth projective variety $X$ over a finite field, is the category of vector bundles defined on a neighborhood of the $Y$ equivalent to the category of vector bundles on the formal neighborhood of $Y$ ($\text{dim}Y\geq 2$)? This is asking whether $\text{Leff(Y,X)}$ holds or not (This is true if we work over an algebraically closed field)

This seems to be true in the case of very ample divisors (one hypersurface). [This example](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0EL6) claims it to be true without assumptions on the field. The example does not claim the extension is unique on the neighborhood, so I am wondering whether an ample divisor $Y$ in a smooth projective variety $X$ of dimension $\geq 3$ satisfies $\text{Leff}(Y,X)$ or not? (field is not algebraically closed)

Comment: The cited example refers to [this proposition](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0EL5), which comes with a proof. So, what is the question exactly?

Comment: So the question is whether Hartshorne's theorem of $Leff(Y,X)$ holds over non-algebraically closed fields like finite fields or not. Another one is whether an ample divisor has the property $Leff(Y,X)$ or not over arbitrary field. The example claims there is an extension from formal neighborhood to a neighborhood but does not claim it is unique.

Comment: Over arbitrary fields, for the hypersurface case, Lef(Y, X) is https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0EL2 and Leff(Y, X) is https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0EL7. This trivially implies the result for a complete intersection by composing restriction functors several times.